# Magic square in AMPL: presolve: constraint cannot hold

Tags: ampl

I'm solving the magic square problem without using the `alldiff` operator.

To insert different values ​​in the matrix, I initialized a variable:

`var y {1..n, 1..n, 1..n * n} binary;`

where `y[i,j,k]` will equal 1 if and only if entry `i, j` in the matrix equals `k`. Then each cell contains exactly one number is given by:

`s.t. OneEach {i in 1..n, j in 1..n}: sum {k in 1..n * n} y[i,j,k] = 1;`

and the constraint that all entries are different is given by:

`s.t. AllDifferent {k in 1..n * n}: sum {i in 1..n, j in 1..n} y[i,j,k] <= 1;`

My problem now is to formalize the constraint that the sum on the rows, columns and on the diagonals is equal to the magic constant. I tried with

`s.t. RowsSum {k in 1..n * n}: sum {i in 1..n, j in 1..n} k * y [i, j, k] = constant;`

`s.t. ColsSum {k in 1..n * n}: sum {i in 1..n, j in 1..n} k * y [j, i, k] = constant;`

An additional constraint is used to calculate the value of the constant:

`s.t. q1: ((k*k)/2)*(k*k+1) = constant*k;`

But when I load the model, he tells me:

`presolve: constraint ColsSum [1] cannot hold: body> = 15 cannot be <= 9; difference = 6`
`presolve: constraint RowsSum [1] cannot hold: body> = 15 cannot be <= 9; difference = 6`

Without the constraints on the sum of rows and columns, the result is this:

```
Magic_Constant = 15

  1   2   3
  4   5   6
  7   8   9
```

The value of the magic constant is right, the square works because there are all the numbers from `1` to `n^2`, and they also appear only once. But now I must add that the sums on rows and columns must be equal to the magic constant.

Tips?