# Same values constraint and grouping of variables

Tags: linear-programming, combinatorial-optimization, binary-variable, logical-constraints

In a linear program, I would like some variables to:
1.  Take the same values 
2.  Group some variables i.e. some variables should take same values or lie within certain percentage.
3.  All different values

The objective function is given by:
[image]

Comment: You specified $x_i \ge 0$ for all $i$.  For (2), did you maybe mean $>0$ instead of $\ge 0$?

Comment: Yes, I intended to say greater than zero in (2) and not greater than equal to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1) This is correct, and there's nothing wrong with having a whole lot of constraints that each require $x_6 = x_j$ for some $j$. But if you know in advance that these variables will all equal each other, why not just define a new variable that equals all of them? That is, create a variable $x_{6-10}$ that equals $x_6$ through $x_{10}$ and use this variable everywhere any of the $x_6$ through $x_{10}$ variables appear?

(2) Using the logic described [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/33/in-an-integer-program-how-i-can-force-a-binary-variable-to-equal-1-if-some-cond), you can create a binary variable $y_6$ that equals 1 if $x_6 \ge 0$, and another binary variable $y_8$ that equals 1 if $x_8 \ge 0$. Then you can enforce the "if-then" implications using the logic described [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/76/in-an-integer-program-how-can-i-activate-a-constraint-only-if-a-decision-vari).

(3) Some solvers have a built-in feature that allows you to specify that certain variables must be different from each other; see [Matrix in ampl: constraint that the values ​are all different](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/2896/matrix-in-ampl-constraint-that-the-values-are-all-different). But I think this only works for integer variables. For continuous variables, I think you need to use big-Ms for this, although maybe others will chime in with better ideas.

Comment: Thank you. As Rob pointed out the ambiguity in my question (2), I intended to say greater than zero in (2) and not greater than equal to zero. Would this change your answer?

Comment: You can't really do strict inequalities for continuous variables. The best you can do is something like $x_i \ge \delta$ for some small $\delta > 0$. Then the logic described in the answers linked to above still applies.